# Can I use a price of $0.00 in Google Analytics eCommerce tracking?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce

Is there a minimum price for use with `addItem` (e.g. `_gaq.push(['_addItem', ...]);`) and friends?

I've checked [the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiEcommerce.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addItem), but I can't find any info either way on whether I have to give a minimum price (like `'0.01'`, if I can call free items free `'0.00'`, or even if you can make prices negative `'-1.50'`).

We have some code that uses `'0.01'` for items that should really be called `'0.00'`, so I'd like to correct this if possible, but I'd like to make sure it's supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this will work just fine.

(Not only will it work, but if you mistakenly pass a non-numeric string, like, "thisisnotanumber", the default behavior is for Google Analytics to interpret it as $0.00. So, it's actually the standard fallback behavior when it can't parse the number out.)

Comment: Great, thank you -- I had started setting up a staging Google Analytics account for testing this (which I'm just going to finish for testing other changes).  Do negative amounts (e.g. `'-1.50'`, maybe for a coupon or something) work as well, or is `'0.00'` as low as it goes?

Comment: Gotcha, thanks.  I remember seeing that on another page now about how to "delete" transactions (you can't delete, you can only cancel them out by refunding).  Thanks for your help -- I really don't know why this code was calling these items `'0.01'` now.  :P